# OpenAM does not allow login in a realm if using Cross Domain SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, openam

I have try this to configure login to a specific realm in the Jboss Agent:

https://backstage.forgerock.com/#!/docs/openam/12.0.0/admin-guide/chap-realms#realms-agents

But it does not work if Cross Domain SSO is enabled. Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Saludos
Andres

Answer (score 1):

In case of CDSSO you should modify the com.sun.identity.agents.config.cdsso.cdcservlet.url property in the agent profile (add ?realm=/foo to the URL).